# jQuery selector with "and" and "or"

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Can somebody help me with the syntax of what I'm trying to do here?

```
jQuery('(div[data-positiontype="3"]) && (div[data-positiontitle*="test"] || div[data-positiondesc*='test'])')
```

Basically I need the ability to select all divs that have a particular "data-positiontype" attribute and a token in either the "data-positiontitle" attribute or the "data-positiondesc" attribute.

Comment: `$('div[data-positiontype="3"]').filter('[data-positiontitle*="test"], [data-positiondesc*="test"]')`

Comment: But really, you need to review [how selectors work](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Comment: jQuery selectors are in most cases identical to css selectors. How would you do this in css?

Comment: @zzzzBov In my defense, .filter is mentioned nowhere in the selectors documentation.

Comment: @Kyle, then you should review the entire [jQuery api](http://api.jquery.com). If you don't know what tools you have available, how can you ever hope to accomplish anything with them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('div[data-positiontype="3"]').filter('[data-positiontitle*="test"], [data-positiondesc*="test"]').
```

or the straightforward:

```
$('div[data-positiontype="3"][data-positiontitle*="test"], div[data-positiontype="3"][data-positiondesc*="test"]').
```

Comment: .filter() Amazing! Just what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

You stack the selectors together to find elements that matches both, and use the `,` combinator between selectors:

```
jQuery('div[data-positiontype="3"][data-positiontitle*="test"],div[data-positiontype="3"][data-positiondesc*="test"]')
```